# LWUIT in a enterprise J2ME application?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lcdui

We are developing a J2ME application and sometimes we face constraints while working with the default lcdui library. Whenever we want some extra in the UI, the only option is to work with canvas which is not so easy. Now we are thinking to use LWUIT as UI library instead of ludui but having some question before starting -

1. Is LWUIT mature enough to be used in a enterprise J2ME application?
2. Can  we mix LWUIT and LCDUI in same application ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In my point of view. lwuit is mature enough to be used in enterprise applications. It's still in permanent development and it's progressing fast.
2. Yes you can mix both of them. If you use an lwuit form you can only add lwuit components and vice versa. It should be possible to implement and draw you own container objects (canvas style).

Comment: The only problem I have seen with lwuit is the licensing. One of my clients gave up using it because of some terms Oracle updated.

Answer (score 0):

LWUIT is mature enough to be used as enterprise application and though J2ME has some limited classes when we talk about JDK but still its mature enough to build many applications